# watchOS Complications: How to add context-based deep-links?

Tags: deep-linking, watchos, apple-watch-complication

I want to create complications that when tapped open the watch app to a specific section in the app. I am using CloudKit and `CLKComplicationDataSource`.
Apple documentation even recommends deep-linking, but I haven't been able to find out how to do this. There is another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838581/watchos-complications-deep-link-to-a-page-in-the-app) but no correct answer.

Note: I need to support watchOS versions below 9, so I cannot use widgetKit and I must use ClockKit (in case that makes a difference)

Here is what [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/system-experiences/complications/):
[image]